# Can someone check If this extension is correct?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-extensions

I had to find $a$ such that $\mathbb Q(2^{1/4}):\mathbb Q$ is equal to $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2)(a)$
But i found that $a=2^{1/4}$, is that right?

For it i used that $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2) =$ { $a+b\sqrt 2$} and then tried with $2^{1/4}$. 
I found { $a+b\sqrt 2+ c2^{1/4}+d\sqrt 2 + e\sqrt 2 + f \sqrt 2*2^{1/4} +  g \sqrt 2* 2^{1/4} + 2h$ }

Comment: It may be right. Perhaps if you show how you find it, it would be easier to answer your question.

Comment: I actually Just tried and found the same base, but Will edit question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extension $\Bbb Q(\sqrt 2)(2^{1/4})$ is
$$
\{a + b2^{1/4}\mid a, b\in \Bbb Q(\sqrt 2)\}
$$
Rewriting that in terms of $\Bbb Q$ we get
$$
\{(a_1+a_2\sqrt 2) + (b_1 + b_2\sqrt 2)2^{1/4}\mid a_i, b_i\in \Bbb Q\}\\
\{a_1+a_2\sqrt 2 + b_12^{1/4} + b_22^{1/4}\sqrt 2\mid a_i, b_i\in \Bbb Q\}
$$
In general, if $\Bbb Q\subseteq \Bbb Q(x)\subseteq \Bbb Q(y)$ are field extensions, then we always have $\Bbb Q(x)(y) = \Bbb Q(y)$ (and there is nothing special about $\Bbb Q$ here, or the fact that the extensions have single generators).

Comment: Thank you a Lot, that's intetesting

Answer (score 0):

In the proof for multiplicativity or degrees in towers, we find that when $F/E$ has basis $\{\alpha_\lambda\}$, $E/K$ has basis $\{\beta_\mu\}$, then $F/K$ has basis $\{\alpha_\lambda\beta_\mu\}$.

But in this case n this case, $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{2})(\sqrt[4]{2}) = \Bbb Q(\sqrt{2})$. Which has basis over $\Bbb Q$ all linear combinations of the powers of $\sqrt{2}$ with coefficients in $\Bbb Q$, from the $0$ power up to one less than the degree of the minimal polynomial for $\sqrt{2}$ over $\Bbb Q$, which is 2. So it as basis $\{1, \sqrt{2}\}$ over $\Bbb Q$.